# iOS String.drawAtPoint always renders at the same size

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, ios9

I have code that draws text inside a CALayer:

```
override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext) {
        ...

        // text
        print ("font attributes: \(slider.thumbTextFontDescriptor.fontAttributes())")
        if text != lastText {
            lastTextSize = text.sizeWithAttributes(slider.thumbTextFontDescriptor.fontAttributes())
            lastText = text
        }

        let textPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(thumbFrame) - lastTextSize.width / 2.0,CGRectGetMidY(thumbFrame) - lastTextSize.height / 2.0)
        UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
        text.drawAtPoint(textPoint, withAttributes: slider.thumbTextFontDescriptor.fontAttributes())
        UIGraphicsPopContext()

}
```

example of the print output:

```
font attributes: ["NSFontNameAttribute": HelveticaNeue-Light, "NSFontSizeAttribute": 60]
```

the font descriptor is initialized as

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 60.0) {
    thumbTextFontDescriptor = font.fontDescriptor()
}
```

The symptom that I have: the text is always drawn with the same size and probably the same font.

I can set the font size to 10.0 or to 60.0, the rendering result is always the same.

When I comment out the line "text.drawAtPoint..." no text is rendered, so I'm sure this is the code that renders.

This is iOS 9 GM, XCode 7 GM

Any idea why the attributes seem not to be respected by text.drawAtPoint?

Comment: Try using the `UITextAttributeFont` key and pass in a `UIFont` as the value.

Comment: my print is now font attributes: ["NSFontNameAttribute": HelveticaNeue-Light, "UITextAttributeFont": <UICTFont: 0x143d63ee0> font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 30.00pt, "NSFontSizeAttribute": 30]    -  and I see no difference.

Comment: You just need the one attribute. Get rid of the name and size ones.

Comment: Yes, something like  text.drawAtPoint(textPoint, withAttributes:[NSFontAttributeName:font])   works. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that

`slider.thumbTextFontDescriptor.fontAttributes()`

isn't returning the correct kind of dictionary required for the `drawAtPoint:` method. I've just tried the following simplified version of your code and it worked ok on an older Xcode (6.3)

```
let text = "test"

if let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 60.0) {
  let textPoint = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
  text.drawAtPoint(textPoint, withAttributes:[NSFontAttributeName:font])

}
```

Comment: That's it. I assumed those dictionaries were designed to work together.